# AngularJs validation for particular select

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a dropdown in which when I select 'one' only then my input appears. That input is required field. What I want is when user select 'one' only then validation on the input works and hence on save button it shows error but if it selects other values or no value then on save it doesn't show validation error.

```
<form name="myForm" data-ng-submit="save(myForm.$valid)"novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-6">Select:</label>
      <select class="col-md-2" ng-model="val.value">
            <option value="1" selected>one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
      </select>               
      <div ng-show="val.value=='1'">
         <label class="col-md-3">one:</label>
         <input type="number" class="col-md-4" ng-model="val.one" name="valOne" data-ng-class="{'has-error':myForm.valOne.$dirty && myForm.valOne.$invalid }" required="required"/>
         <div class="col-md-2" data-ng-messages="myForm.valOne.$error"
         data-ng-show="myForm.valOne.$touched ||myForm.$submitted">
            <div class="error-message" data-ng-message="required">Please enter Value
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>                                
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>
       Save</button>
</form>
```

Please recommend something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-required:

```
 <input type="number" class="col-md-4" ng-model="val.one" name="valOne" data-ng-class="{'has-error':myForm.valOne.$dirty && myForm.valOne.$invalid }" ng-required="val.value == 1"/>
```

Comment: its pleasure to help!

Comment: one error happened @Jenny. when I click on save once the code doesn't work but when I click on it twice it does. why so?